# How to access result array returned in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Arg!! I had this working flawlessly and now I am back to banging head against the keyboard.

I want access defined columns inside the array, but I am getting undefined but if I display the results using an alert as detailed in snipped of code below I see the following:

```
[{"firstname":" Mr","0":" Mr","lastname":" Two","1":" Two","user_public_info_id":"3","2":"3","st_usage_id":null,"3":null},{"firstname":" Mr","0":" Mr","lastname":" Three","1":" Three","user_public_info_id":"5","2":"5","st_usage_id":null,"3":null}] 
*** 
g 
*** 
e 
*** 
undefined
```

Here is the Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "models/ajaxHandler.php",
 data: "handler=getStActivitySharingList&stu_id="+stu_id,
 datatype: "json",
 success: function(result){
    var count = 0;
    if (result !== null)
    {
       //display results
       alert(result + " <br />*** <br />" + result[0] +" <br />*** <br />" + result[1] + " <br />*** <br />"  + result[0]["firstname"]);

       //clears choice list
       clearOptions();

       //result = $.parseJSON(result); //if this is used cannot display result again
       alert (result);   

       $.each(result, function (i, elem) {
           alert("elem"+elem.st_usage_id );    //displays as undefined and won't break
           if (elem.st_usage_id === null)
           {
               count++;
               alert(elem.firstname + " "+ elem.lastname + " " + elem.user_public_info_id);
               appendOption(elem);
           }
       });              
     }
     alert(count);
     if (count === 0){
         noResultsAvailableOption();
     }else{
        resultsAvailableOption();
      }

        ShowDialog(false);
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      error: function(){
           alert("ajax failure: could not retrieve a list of contacts");
      }
  });
```

Comment: You seem to be doing it right, but `st_usage_id` is null on your example records.

Comment: `datatype` -> `dataType`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Comment: @bfavaretto - correct - but that alert is never reached. as you can see from my out put if i call result[0]['firstname'] i get an undefined.

Comment: And it didn't work even after fixing the typo noted by Kevin B?

Comment: @KevinB if it is a typo than explain why the error method is returned when I make your change? If it is lowercase I am getting results?

Comment: Because your json is probably invalid. This is where **you** start debugging what your server is returning.

Comment: alert result to see what's actually being returned. It starts with "ge".

Comment: @bfavaretto I get the error method called if I change the 'typo'. I am returning the results from PHP using echo json_encode($results); I just cannot access a particular element in the array. I get undefined or a single character.

Comment: if you don't fix the typo, your result is beign returned as a string, which is why `"yourjsonstringhere"[0].someproperty` is undefined.

Comment: @bfavaretto   I have the output included in the post above. The result is the first line. I tried various ways to output a single element of the result set.

Comment: @user2672744 if result[0] and result[1] are `g` and `e` respectively, then the first line is preceded by some additional text. Try `alert("geaux tigers!"[0])`

Comment: @KevinB now the error method is being called. I tested the server side code and it works. But now it appears that the call is not even being posted now.

Comment: I got to run.... but I will continue this tmw! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better answer this question is to implement better debugging procedures.

Here is the code that I used for debugging this issue. The breaking down of the xmlHttpRequest clearly displayed to me that issue was with the data and that I was encountering an illegal character exception when trying to encode the data to json.

A great way to solve any issue is to first implement the correct debugging procedures, and everything else will work itself out.

```
error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, error){
    alert("ajax failure: could not populate list of countires | " + status + " | error:" + error);
    var xmlHttpRequestStr= "";
    for(x in xmlHttpRequest)
         xmlHttpRequestStr = xmlHttpRequestStr + xmlHttpRequest[x];
    alert(xmlHttpRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i not know how you return it from PHP, but in jquery try:

```
sucess: function (result)
{
    console.log(JSON.parse(result)); // parse string to json
}
```

See [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html)